# Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK remove attribute with dependencies

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I'm having troubles with removing the attribute of entity which have dependencies from SDK.
To remove an attribute I need:

1. RetrieveAttribute
2. RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest
3. DeleteRelationshipRequest
4. and finally DeleteAttributeRequest

I would be appreciated for any advise about the plan above or sample code. 
I couldn't find example at msdn so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears that the `RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest` is telling you that you have to delete a relationship before you can delete the attribute; and you are doing so.

I expect that this is a look-up attribute?
Is it visible in the entity form?

You won't be able to delete the attribute as long as the entity form has a dependency on it.