# How to find unused/non-dependent fields of any entity in CRM 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to identify unused or non-dependent fields of any *entity* in *Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011*. By unused or non-dependent i mean the field that is not used in any of the entity *forms*.

I have googled to find on the same topic but couldn't get the desired results. One link that i have come across also doesn't address this problem:
[Finding unused CRM fields](http://www.salentica.com/finding-unused-crm-fields/)

Comment: I'm on a plane at the moment or I'd try to dive into this more for you, but it looks like this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926164/dynamics-crm-2011-sdk-remove-attribute-with-dependencies ... in summary, you use the retrieve dependencies requests to check to see if any attribute has no dependencies.

Comment: Thanks but this is not what i am looking for. In actual, `RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest` returns a list of all the dependencies for solution components that could prevent deleting a solution component. Which has nothing to do with field dependency on an entity as mentioned in the question.

Comment: On the contrary, it does, I just phrased it poorly :). I'll post an answer here shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I should note that just checking if a field is not on a form does not mean it is not being used somewhere. There is a chance if you have a third party integration, or other logic running on an entity that it could be updating hidden fields. If you're unsure if there is data stored for an attribute you can do a retrieve request where your condition is that the attribute is not null. If nothing comes back then there is no data stored for that attribute.

Assuming that is already clear, what you'd want to do is utilize Dynamics CRM's Dependency Tracking to check for dependencies of individual attributes.

Here's the full article on Dependency Tracking for CRM 2011: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309749.aspx

The request that sounds most like what you're looking for is the [`RetrieveDependentComponentsRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.retrievedependentcomponentsrequest.aspx). This request seems to be the closest match according to what you're looking for and per the documentation:

> Returns a list of dependencies for solution components that directly depend on a solution component.
>   For example, when you use this message for a global option set solution component, dependency records for solution components representing any option set attributes that reference the global option set solution component are returned.
>   When you use this message for the solution component record for the account entity, dependency records for all of the solution components representing attributes, views, and forms used for that entity are returned.

The basic steps to accomplish what you're looking for would then be:

1. Execute a [`RetrieveEntityRequest`](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/b66443f8-e1d2-4821-9027-edb3b8b90303) to retrieve all the attributes for a particular entity
2. For each attribute in the response, execute a `RetreiveDependentComponentsRequest` where you set the `ObjectId` to the `MetadataId` of the attribute, and the [`ComponentType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328546.aspx#bkmk_componenttype) to be 2 (attribute).
3. Parse the `EntityCollection` property on the response to see if any of the dependencies have a `ComponentType` of 24 (form).

Comment: Please share sample code specific to my requirement to get all the unused fields of an entity.

Comment: @FSX As the code would take a significant bit of time to write, I straight up do not have the time to write the entire solution for you. I will update my answer to be a bit more clear on the exact steps I would take in your situation though.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. Atleast now i have some better idea how to do it. Further a form can be of type SystemForm as well with value 60. Correct?

Comment: @FSX That looks correct. I see that SystemForm is exposed on the API as a regular entity so you should be able to retrieve it's name by querying on the Id passed back in the dependency request's result.

Comment: @GotDibbs - great summary, MSDN documentation doesn't mention that MetadataId and SolutionComponentId are interchangeable which is what got me stuck.